# Using a port other than 80 with lighttpd on Mac OS?

Tags: mac, webserver, lighttpd

I've just installed lighttpd on Mac OS 10.6, but:

```
$ lighttpd -f lighttpd.conf -D
2011-10-05 19:01:32: (network.c.358) can't bind to port:  80 Permission denied 
$ lsof -i :80
[a ton of processes]
```

How can I start lighttpd on a different port?

Comment: comment doesn't accept formatting, I'm cutting and attaching as answer for the sake of readability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options:

1. put something like this into your `lighttpd.conf`:

   ```
   server.port = 8000
   ```
2. launch `lighttpd` with admin-rights via `sudo`:

   ```
   $> sudo lighttpd -f lighttpd.conf -D
   ```

Also read the [`lighthttpd` configuration tutorial](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/TutorialConfiguration.).

Answer (score 0):

You've already been answered about how to set a specific port but there are still two points to be highlighted in your question:

1. as regular user you cannot bind TCP/IP ports below 1024, a common threshold for system services, hence the *permission denied* error
2. the ton of processes come from listing your user's outgoing connection (probably web browsing); filter listening and privileged port instead:

   sudo lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN

The first point may eliminate the need to change default port, since it seems you wanted to change it in order to avoid the permission error.

On OS X ensure system's httpd is off when trying to start your own webserver, it's set with System Preferences -> Sharing -> Web Sharing checkbutton.